# Async and Await : Error In MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

Hi I have a problem to use Async And Wait in my following method. 
Basically I used Neevia Converter to Convert My Document and I want to wait my method until conversion to be completed.

Could you please help:

```
public void AsyncAndWaitTillExecutionMethod(string fileName) {
      CallForConverter(fileName);
    }

    private async void CallForConverter(string fileName) {
        var result = await CallForConverterAsync(fileName);
    }

    private Task<string> CallForConverterAsync(string fileName) {
        string fromLocation;
        string toLocation;

        // For  data source
        string fileFullName = fileName;
        fromLocation = "abc"; 
        toLocation = "xyz";
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConvertUsingNeevia(fromLocation, toLocation));

    }
    private string ConvertUsingNeevia(string from, string to) {
        string success = "false";

        int TimeOut = 3000;
        try {
            Neevia.docConverter NVDC = new Neevia.docConverter();
            int Res = NVDC.convertFile(from, to, TimeOut);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception("Exception ", ex);
        }
        success = "True";
        return success;

    }
```

It is giving me the Following Error From the CallForConverter() method. 
An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle in MVC...

Comment: AsyncAndWaitTillExecutionMethod doesn't really wait for the execution. Also, what kind of public method name is that? Don't use "async void" unless you really have to (like in an event handler). Use Task.Run instead of Task.Factory.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove all `async`, `await`, and (the horrible) `StartNew` from your code:

```
public void AsyncAndWaitTillExecutionMethod(string fileName) {
    string fromLocation;
    string toLocation;

    // For  data source
    string fileFullName = fileName;
    fromLocation = "abc"; 
    toLocation = "xyz";
    ConvertUsingNeevia(fromLocation, toLocation);
}
```

Comment: Yes, all of this did nothing.

Comment: then its not handling multiple requests.

Comment: I feel like 90% of the async usage in ASP.NET is from people who don't know what it does.

Comment: @ABMAbdulMuttalib: Sure it will; ASP.NET is parallelized for you. If you mean multiple requests *from the same session*, then you should look into disabling session state for those requests.

Comment: Problem is that its takes ages to convert docs; 10-15 secs avg, so by this time another user request temp folder still busy with conversion, that causing error. otherwise neevia maintain queue should be fine.

Comment: @ABMAbdulMuttalib: Um, if there's a temp folder conflict, then making this  synchronous, asynchronous, or fire-and-forget will not have any difference.